# WPF - using CroppedBitmap in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, crop, bitmapimage

The following xaml works ok inside a `Window`:

```
<Border Width="45" Height="55" CornerRadius="10" >
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush>
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <CroppedBitmap Source="profile.jpg" SourceRect="0 0 45 55"/>
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>    
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

But when I use the equivalent code in a `DataTemplate` I get the following error in run-time:

> *Failed object initialization*
>   *(ISupportInitialize.EndInit). 'Source'*
>   *property is not set.  Error at object*
>   *'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.CroppedBitmap'*
>   *in markup file. 
>  Inner Exception:*
>   *{"'Source' property is not set."}*

The only difference is that I have the `CroppedBitmap`'s Source property data-bound:

```
<CroppedBitmap Source="{Binding Photo}" SourceRect="0 0 45 55"/>
```

What gives?

**UPDATE:** According to an [old post by Bea Stollnitz](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=16) this is a limitation of the source property of the `CroppedBitmap`, because it implements `ISupportInitialize`. (This information is down the page - do a search on "11:29" and you'll see).
Is this still an issue with .Net 3.5 SP1?

Comment: The link to Bea Stollnitz's blog is dead & I can find no archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the XAML parser creates CroppedBitmap, it does the equivalent of:

```
var c = new CroppedBitmap();
c.BeginInit();
c.Source = ...    OR   c.SetBinding(...
c.SourceRect = ...
c.EndInit();
```

`EndInit()` requires `Source` to be non-null.

When you say `c.Source=...`, the value is always set before the EndInit(), but if you use `c.SetBinding(...)`, it tries to do the binding immediately but detects that `DataContext` has not yet been set.  Therefore it defers the binding until later.  Thus when `EndInit()` is called, `Source` is still null.

This explains why you need a converter in this scenario.

Comment: I know this is a very old topic, but I'm having the same issue. What converter do I need to make? Thx for any help!

Comment: Can you expand on where the converter is needed? For which attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would complete [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726339/3195477) by providing the alluded-to Converter.

Now I use this converter and that seems to work, no more Source' property is not set error.

```
public class CroppedBitmapConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        FormatConvertedBitmap fcb = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
        fcb.BeginInit();
        fcb.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        fcb.EndInit();
        return fcb;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The mentioned Bea Stollnitz's blog is now gone -- I'm not sure where/how to use your converter. I tried `<CroppedBitmap Source="{Binding PortraitPath, Converter={StaticResource croppedBitmapConverter}}" SourceRect="{Binding PortraitBounds}"/>` but I still got the `Source` property not set error. Happen to remember how you did it?