# IValueConverter gets null value - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, converters, ivalueconverter

I am trying to use CroppedBitmap.

The path of the image is known only during run time, so I want to set CroppedBitomap.Source  via Binding.

I found out that there is a known issue with CroppedBitmap and its Source. see: [WPF - using CroppedBitmap in DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711151/wpf-using-croppedbitmap-in-datatemplate)

These link recommend to use a converter.
I tried doing it, but I always get null value inside the Convert function.

Here is a xaml view:

```
<UserControl> 
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="testLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Img}"/>
        <Button x:Name="testButton" Content="{Binding ElementName=testLabel, Path=Content}"/>

        <Image Stretch="None">
            <Image.Source>
                <CroppedBitmap Source="{Binding ElementName=testLabel, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" SourceRect="10,10,50,50" />            
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The label named "testLabel" shows the value from the property Img with no problem.
The button "testButton" shows the same value as "testLabel".

Here is the class imageConverter:

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            FormatConvertedBitmap fcb = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
            fcb.BeginInit();
            fcb.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
            fcb.EndInit();
            return fcb;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
        }
}
```

But when I debug the function Convert I see that the first argument named "value" always  gets null.

Gurus, I need your help.

Comment: If value is null, then it's a problem with the binding, not with the converter...

Comment: I guess you are right. the problem is that I use the same binding for "testButton" and it works there. is there a different datacontext inside an image control?

Comment: For the Image control, the DataContext is the same, but perhaps not for the CroppedBitmap itself, because it's not part of the visual tree... Check the output windows in VS to see if there are binding errors. If you see something like "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement...", it's because the binding can't find the DataContext

Comment: I don't see such messages. is there any other way to view images (on a specific dimension) but without using CroppedBitmap?

Comment: Why did you bind to testLabel.Content instead of Img? No need to bind to the element when you bind straight to the source.

Comment: When I bind the Img directly, I see that it go inside the property get function and gets a correct value, but then it send a null value to the converter. So I tried to get it from another element, but it also sends null value. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please post the code for the Img Property

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

My error was that the bound Property was the wrong type. It was string should have been an enum.

No build error.
But at run time my (IValueConverter).Convert method gets passed value=null.

Where this happens - check the bindings ...